# populate null columns in database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to populate a currency value column with a value which is calculated from 2 other columns.

So:

```
original_value    amount         new_value
12                  2             NULL
10                  1             NULL
```

This would become:

```
original_value    amount         new_value
12                  2             24
10                  1             10
```

I only want to update the NULL columns.

This needs to work for SQL Server and MYSQL!

Comment: Don't store computed values (from other columns.) Redundancy, not normalized, risk of data inconsistency! Create a view instead - will always be up to date!

Comment: I know - not our decision!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET new_value = (original_value * amount) 
WHERE new_value IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

As I said in my comment; *don't store computed values (from other columns.) Redundancy, not normalized, risk of data inconsistency! Create a view instead - will always be up to date!*

```
create view viewname as
select original_value, amount, original_value * amount as new_value
from tablename
```

SQL Server has computed columns, do something like:

```
alter table tablename add new_value as original_value * amount
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
UPDATE 
  table_name 
  SET  new_value = original_value * amount 
WHERE 
  new_value is null
```